# Get id of clicked element without putting any js code in the html

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I need to get the ID of an element that was clicked, but I need to to keep all my js and html separate. normally id just use 'this.id' in the html. Any other ways?

Comment: ... you can still refer to the elements from an externally included JS file.

Comment: How are you attaching the click handler to this element?

Comment: Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event

Comment: thanks for replies. I don't know how to attach a handler because I don't know which element will be clicked, so other than making like 20 event handlers i would rather one that attaches to the element i click on

Comment: wazzaday: you can click on anything you want, but either you attach click handlers to the specific elements you want to monitor, or you attach a click handler to EVERYTHING and run a bunch of filtering every time something's clicked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what `e.target` is for. You can add an event listener anywhere you want, as long as the click event is allowed to bubble up to it (which happens by default) you can catch it. A basic example:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
});
```

Clicking on each will alert its id. Hope this helps :)

```
<button id="foo">foo</button>
<button id="bar">bar</button>
<button id="baz">baz</button>
```

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/95NZ8/

Comment: You're welcome :) a standard approach is to attach an event listener to the direct parent of the element(s) you want to listen for; e.g: a `<ul>` element containing a bunch of links. One note: if you're listening for clicks on links you might want to add `e.preventDefault();` to your event listener to trap the event and stop it from executing.

Comment: Oh! I almost forgot to mention one very important point: `addEventListener()` is only supported in IE from version 9. Yes. If you need to support earler versions of IE, read the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent - alternatively, you can use a library like jQuery to normalise cross-browser functionality!

Comment: @wazzaday: you should also mark Darragh's answer as the answer which solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#someWrapper").each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            alert(this.id);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a jQuery tag. Was it removed in an early (grace-period) edit, or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onclick = e => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

to get element, tagname, classname , [other attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44903739/2591092)

```
window.onclick = e => {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.target.tagName);
    console.log(e.target.className);
    console.log(e.target.id);
}
```