# Get id of div cliked on in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

i have this function in javascript :

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    accSelect =document.getElementsByClassName("customSelectorListBox")[0].style.display;
    if(accSelect=="block" ) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("customSelectorListBox")[0].style.display="none";
    }
}, true);
```

How can i get the id of a div I click on, inside this function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get id of clicked element without putting any js code in the html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270824/get-id-of-clicked-element-without-putting-any-js-code-in-the-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function to accept the [event object  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) as argument:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
```

Then you can get the clicked element via [`event.target` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) and access its ID:

```
event.target.id
```

I recommend to read all [the excellent articles about event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) on quirksmode.org.