# how to use this incomplete javascript object in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I got this javascript code to solve in a manner to use inner function but not able to use it. Please try to help me to use inner functions or do i need to modify this. I want to use inner functions on click on html element such as view and remove respectively;

```
var App = function(){ 
    var url = 'api';

    function view(event) {
        var id = '??'; //here i have to receive id of the element(data-id)
        $.ajax({
            url: url + '/view/' +id,
            data: data
        }).done( function (data){

        });
    }

    function remove(event) {
        var id = '??'; //please determine the id
        $.ajax({
            url: url + '/remove/' + id ,
            data: data
        }).done( function (data){

        });
    }

    function initialize() {
        //
    }

    return {
        //
    }

}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

1. For id you can do one thing, Save the id in data-id attribute of the element on which you want onClick listener and access it using Event-Delegation in javascript.
2. To use the inner method you don't need to return anything. Just do it this way :

   ```
       var App = function(){ 
         var url = 'api';

         function view(event) {
          //access the id attribute of event.target
         }

         function remove(event) {
          //same
         } 

         function initialize() {
          //
         }

         App.view = view;
         App.remove = remove;

       };
       //EDIT : instead of making it self-invoking, call the app function                
       App();
       //to access it outside:
       App.view("your_parameter");
       App.remove("your_parameter");
   ```

**EDIT : Instead of making it self-invoking, call the app function**

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7723221/7551566) for how to use id attribute in event listener.

Comment: Cannot set property 'view' of undefined

Comment: Try this :  `function App()
        {
            function view(e){
              //
            }
        
            App.view = view;
        }

        App();
        App.view("Your_parameter");`

Comment: Yeah. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it's pretty simple, use the `$("#caller").click()` function of our beloved

**[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/)**

Then inside the .click() function you can easily retrieve your `id`

[Here](https://api.jquery.com/click/) you can find more on the .click() function

It will be something like this

```
$( "#view" ).click(function() {
     id = document.getElementById("id").id;
     //Here paste the code of your view function
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that i know, My question here is how to use App? or how to initialise it

Comment: Why do you need App? you can just use the $(document).ready()

Comment: so again. the above mentioned javascript is there along with some html. in HTML I have two rows in a table with two actions each named view and remove. now how to use this above mentioned javascript code in a way that when i click on remove. it will call ajax function and do something. how to call these two view and remove function on click of view and remove button respectively.