# TypeScript : How to get paragraph text within div

Tags: html, typescript

I want to get paragraph text within div when I click on div. I tried `getElementsByTagName()` but it doesn't work. Here is the code :

HTML :

```html
<div class="tile" style="left:40px;top:55px;" (click)="getTextFromHiddenParagraph(event)">
    <p>{{this.terms[0].termName}}</p>
    <p hidden>{{this.terms[0].connectionName}}</p>
</div>
```

I would like to access content within hidden paragraph when I click on parent div.

Please help!

Comment: if you could edit your example, so it is more clear that would help you get a fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div (click)="getTextFromHiddenParagraph(div.textContent)" #div>
  <p>{{this.terms[0].termName}}</p>
  <p hidden>{{this.terms[0].connectionName}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used one of the properties of event.target function described on post : [What properties can I use with event.target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723188/what-properties-can-i-use-with-event-target). I just positioned hidden paragraph first and used typescript function :

```
getParagraphText(event)
  {
    var conn;
    conn=event.target.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
    console.log(conn);
  }
```

HTML call :

```
<div class="tile" style="left:40px;top:55px;" (click)=getParagraphText($event)" [class.ClickedTile]="isClickedtile1" id="{{this.terms[0].connectionName}}">
        <p hidden>{{this.terms[0].connectionName}}</p>
        <p>{{this.terms[0].termName}}</p>
    </div>
```